# using signtool.exe to scan files in windows-based application

Tags: c#

I am assigned to implement a windows-based C# program to pickup a folder and use signtool.exe to scan/sign all documents.

I am able to get the list of the files in that folder.  Now how do I use the signtool.exe to sign them?  The client machines don't have the signtool.exe installed anywhere.

Edited:  Instead of using external tool to do signature check, I could use the x509Certificates to check directly.   My solution is below for whoever needs in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You would launch signtool.exe with code similar to:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo("<path.to>\signtool.exe", "<command line arguments>");
var p = Process.Start(info);
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not writing clearly enough on my question.   How do I embed that signtool.exe into the application?  Once my application is deployed to the client machine, the signtool.exe should be there as well.  How would I do it, please?

Comment: You could distribute a zip file containing both your app and signtool.  You could create a simple installer that installed both your app and signtool.  Or you could possibly [embed and extract at runtime the signtool.exe image in your app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725915/how-to-access-a-binary-resource-in-a-c-sharp-application).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it has been a while.  I found a simple solution for this.  Just hope in the future, people would look for it:

```
        public static string CheckSignature(string FileName)
    {
        //X509Certificate2 cert;
        try
        {
            var signer = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(FileName);
            var cert = new X509Certificate2(signer);
            return "Digitally signed by: " + cert.SubjectName.Name;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "NOT digitally signed.";
        }
    }
```

Don't forget including: `using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;`

JPL